# recording screencast on android

Tags: android, galaxy, screencast

I am trying to record a screencast on Galaxy S5 using `adb` on a mac.

```
cd /android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
./adb devices
./adb shell screenrecord --verbose ./sdcard/screencast-recording.mp4
```

After the last line I keep getting some configuration error

```
Main display is 1080x1920 @44.70fps (orientation=0)
Configuring recorder for 1080x1920 video at 4.00Mbps
ERROR: unable to configure codec (err=-2147483648)
WARNING: failed at 1080x1920, retrying at 720x1280
Configuring recorder for 720x1280 video at 4.00Mbps
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Did you look to see if you got the video at the lower resolution? AFAIK, that message is just part of the standard "downgrade the resolution" process.

Comment: So you mean I need to change the resolution? Let me check.

Comment: How do I change the resolution of the phone? I looked in setting and haven't found much yet.

Comment: "So you mean I need to change the resolution?" -- no, I mean you need to look in `./sdcard/screencast-recording.mp4` and see if your MP4 file is there. Though that path looks odd -- use `/sdcard/screencast-recording.mp4`.

Comment: just tried the same on my s5 (vz developer edition on 4.4.2), 
`Main display is 1080x1920 @60.00fps (orientation=0)`
`Configuring recorder for 1080x1920 video at 4.00Mbps`
`Content area is 1080x1920 at offset x=0 y=0`   no downsampling occurred

Comment: when I had `./sdcard/screencast-recording.mp4` there was a file but it had 0 bytes. Now that I have `/sdcard/screencast-recording.mp4` (no .), there is no file at all.

Comment: Actually I see the file now; it took a while to show. But it still says 0 bytes.